# Servlet class is not a javax.servlet.Servlet while deploying a bundle in felix jetty

Tags: servlets, jetty, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I am trying to deploy an OSGI bundle in felix jetty. BootStrap is my class which extends HttpServlet.

I am getting the below Exception at deployment stage :

```
ins.server.servlet.HttpServlet30Dispatcher is not assignable from javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
2018-07-11T07:46:55,044 WARN sure-rest-neo [] web-reactor - unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class com.nokia.mdf.sure.neo.utils.Bootstrap is not a javax.servlet.Servlet
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.checkServletType(ServletHolder.java:519) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:379) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:874) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1404) ~[jetty-webapp-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1366) ~[jetty-webapp-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778) ~[jetty-server-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520) ~[jetty-webapp-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
```

I have embedded all dependencies including the transitive ones. How to resolve this, which I assume is due to jar conflict ?

Comment: Are you using the jetty osgi artifacts for this? or just the standard http server features of osgi?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is exactly with embedding dependencies. When you embed the javax.servlet package then your bundle will use the embedded class while jetty will use the class available from an exported package. So while these classes are named the same there are different instances in the classloaders which leads to exactly this kind of error.

To generally solve this you make sure that ideally only one bundle exports each package and all bundles that need it import the package. So the easiest solution is to not embed dependencies.

If that does not work for you then you can try to import and export the javax.servlet package in your bundle. This allows the OSGi environment to decide which package it will actually wire and avoid having the same class names with different instances in bundles.